# npm -v gives a message followed by version

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

I have installed nodejs LTS , from https://nodejs.org/en/. No issues during installation. but the following message appears when `npm -v` is executed in cmd.

> ```
> C:\Users\Praga>node -v
> v14.16.1
>
> C:\Users\Praga>npm -v
> 'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules
> \npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> 6.14.12
>
> C:\Users\Praga>
> ```

`node.exe` exists in `C:\Program Files\nodejs` and `PATH` in environment variables is set right. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:** Below is the path in System variables:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\lenovo\easyplussdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

I am using windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Drop the trailing backslash "\" in your path by editing your environment variables.

Instead of looking like this:

```
<rest-of-path>;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

it should look like this:

```
<rest-of-path>;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

It appears that node or some other code is prefixing the completed file path with its own backslash. That's why you're seeing them doubled in the error message.

Comment: Hi, dropped the "\" , made a restart but no change. I still get the same message in cmd.